# node.js new element add and remove

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, checkbox

When I click on the add button, the text written in textbox should be added on the checkbox
And when I click on the remove button, the checked item should be removed

When I click on the add button, the text written in textbox should be added on the checkbox
And when I click on the remove button, the checked item should be removed

```js
var ul=document.getElementById('list');
var li;

document.getElementById('add').addEventListener('click',add)
document.getElementById('remove').addEventListener('click',remove)

function remove(){
    //console.log('click remove')
    li=ul.children
    for(var i=0;i<li.length;i++){
        if (li[i].children[0].checked==1) 
            ul.removeChild(li[i])  
    }
}

function add(){
    // console.log('click add')
    var inputType=document.getElementById('input').value;
    var textnode=document.createTextNode('inputType')
    if (inputType==='') {
        return false
    } else {
        //create li
        li=document.createElement('li')

        //create checkbox
        var checkebox=document.createElement('input')
        checkebox.type='checkbox'
        checkebox.setAttribute('id','check')

        //create label
        var label=document.createElement('label')
        label.setAttribute('for','item')

        //add to webpages
        ul.appendChild(label)
        li.appendChild(checkbox)
        ul.appendChild(textnode)
        li.appendChild(label)
        ul.insertBefore(li,ul.childNodes[0])
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Add_Remove</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <input type="text" id="input" placeholder="Add Value"/><br>
        <button type="submit" id="add"> Add </button><br>
        <button type="submit" id="remove"> Remove </button>
    </div>
    <ul id="list">
        <li>
            <label><input type="checkbox" id="Music" />Music</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label><input type="checkbox" id="Cricket" />Cricket</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label><input type="checkbox" id="Mobile" />Mobile</label>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <script src="addRemove.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

help me to solve my mistake
what is mistake

Comment: `li.appendChild(checkbox)` checkbox is undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var ul = document.getElementById('list');
var li;

document.getElementById('add').addEventListener('click', add)
document.getElementById('remove').addEventListener('click', remove)

function remove() {
  console.log('click remove')
  li = Object.assign([], ul.children)
  const listLength = li.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < listLength; i++) {
    if (li[i].children[0].children[0].checked == true)
      ul.removeChild(li[i])
  }
}

function add() {
  console.log('click add')
  var inputType = document.getElementById('input').value;
  var textnode = document.createTextNode('inputType')
  if (inputType === '') {
    return false
  } else {
    //create li
    li = document.createElement('li')

    //create checkbox
    var checkebox = document.createElement('input')
    checkebox.type = 'checkbox'
    checkebox.textContent = inputType
    checkebox.setAttribute('id', inputType)

    //create label
    var label = document.createElement('label')
    label.setAttribute('for', 'item')
    label.innerHTML = inputType

    //add to webpages
    ul.appendChild(label)
    label.prepend(checkebox)
    //ul.appendChild(textnode)
    li.appendChild(label)
    ul.insertBefore(li, ul.childNodes[0])
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Add_Remove</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <input type="text" id="input" placeholder="Add Value" /><br>
    <button type="submit" id="add"> Add </button><br>
    <button type="submit" id="remove"> Remove </button>
  </div>
  <ul id="list">
    <li>
      <label><input type="checkbox" id="Music" />Music</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label><input type="checkbox" id="Cricket" />Cricket</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label><input type="checkbox" id="Mobile" />Mobile</label>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <script src="addRemove.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: if I select multiple items  
At that time only one item remove.

Comment: Can you please check again. I added Object.assign for creating new li as it was manipulating the original list.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your fixed snippet hopefully.

Few changes. First, you should pass a reference to inputType when creating a textNode, not a string.

Second, you were declarating "checkebox", but referencing "checkbox". *Pay attention to your console errors*.

```js
var ul=document.getElementById('list');
var li;

document.getElementById('add').addEventListener('click',add)
document.getElementById('remove').addEventListener('click',remove)

function remove(){
    //console.log('click remove')
    li=ul.children
    for(var i=0;i<li.length;i++){
        if (li[i].children[0].checked==1) 
            ul.removeChild(li[i])  
    }
}

function add(){
    // console.log('click add')
    var inputType=document.getElementById('input').value;
    var textnode=document.createTextNode(inputType)
    if (inputType==='') {
        return false
    } else {
        //create li
        li=document.createElement('li')
        
        //create checkbox
        var checkebox=document.createElement('input')
        checkebox.type='checkbox'
        checkebox.setAttribute('id','check')

        //create label
        var label=document.createElement('label')
        label.setAttribute('for','item')

        //add to webpages
        li.appendChild(checkebox)
        ul.appendChild(label)
        li.appendChild(textnode)
        li.appendChild(label)
        ul.insertBefore(li,ul.childNodes[0])
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Add_Remove</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <input type="text" id="input" placeholder="Add Value"/><br>
        <button type="submit" id="add"> Add </button><br>
        <button type="submit" id="remove"> Remove </button>
    </div>
    <ul id="list">
        <li>
            <label><input type="checkbox" id="Music" />Music</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label><input type="checkbox" id="Cricket" />Cricket</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label><input type="checkbox" id="Mobile" />Mobile</label>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <script src="addRemove.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: only the add button is work. Remove button not work.

Answer (score -1):

The two buttons was not bind to event: you need to handle the click event on HTML:

```js
<button type="button" id="add" onclick="add()">Add</button><br />
<button type="button" id="remove" onclick="remove()">Remove</button>
```

or into the JS:

```html
document.getElementById('add').addEventListener('click', add)
document.getElementById('remove').addEventListener('click', remove)
```

Please, not also that your JS code not work property. You need to fix it.

Comment: plz read a question not mistake in onclick that is perfect work